# Can I use react-redux to implement third party npm package for apps which are not using react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, npm-package

I have a react app that uses redux for the implementation. Before using redux I was able to successfully publish it as an npm package library and use it as a third party component in another react app.
Then I used redux for the implementation and publish again it by simply run "npm publish" after changing the version. I was able to successfully publish it.
But when I use it as a third party component in another react app which is not using redux, it gives me an error.

Is there any way to publish a package that uses react-redux, for use as a third party component in a react app which is not using redux?

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
D:/test/my-app/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

Comment: Did you found a fix for this? Me to I want to add React-Redux to [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) but as your question state, also let users who not do Redux be able to use my PR

Answer (score 1):

You could use [custom context](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context) to prevent your package's redux store from clashing with a potentially already existing redux store. In that case, you would export your own `Provider` component that created & passed down a redux store and the consumer of your package would need to wrap that Provider around their application.

Comment: Thanks can you show link to some tutorial doing this? Is there any way to publish a package lib that uses react-redux but not import it itself in package.json?

Comment: @Erik I am not aware of any tutorial that has been ever been written on this, sorry. You could ass react-redux as a peerDependency, but at least that would be necessary.